# split a string in list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list containing string values:

```
a_list = ['1/one','2/two','3/three']
```

I want to split the number from a word like this:

```
number = [1,2,3]
words = [one,two,three]
```

Then I make a condition if the number equal one or three then add the numbers to a new list. here is my code:

```
import re
new_list = []

for i in a_list:   

   word =re.findall(r"[\w']+",i)[1]
   number = re.findall(r"[\w']+",i)[0]
   if  word == 'one' or word == 'three' :
      new_list.append(number)
```

I got an error :

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

any help?... Thanks in advance

Comment: It works fine when I executed.

Comment: please check if you have any dirty data. It works fine for me, too